# How to get vertical ViewPager curl page animation in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation, swipe, android-pagetransformer

I am implementing a `ViewPager` for vertical scrolling. I have used `ViewPager.PageTransformer` for animation.

Below is my code.

```
public class VerticalPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
    private float MIN_SCALE = 1f;

    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
        int pageWidth = view.getWidth();

        if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            view.setAlpha(0);


        } else if (position <= 0) { // [-1,0]
            // Use the default slide transition when moving to the left page
            view.setAlpha(1);
            //view.setTranslationX(1);
            view.setScaleX(1);
            view.setScaleY(1);
            float yPosition = position * view.getHeight();
            view.setTranslationY(yPosition);
            view.setTranslationX(-1 * view.getWidth() * position);

        } else if (position <= 1) { // (0,1]
            // Fade the page out.
            view.setAlpha(1 - position);

            view.setTranslationX(-1 * view.getWidth() * position);

            // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
            float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE
                    + (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
            view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
            view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

        } else { // (1,+Infinity]
            // This page is way off-screen to the right.
            view.setAlpha(0);
        }

    }

}
```

I want to make animation like this

[image]

Comment: So a blurred image comes with the scroll and goes away when the data loading completes. Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: Or anybody help me to remove animation for vertical viewpager so that I can achieved my desired output.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `ViewPager2`, which supports vertical orientation out of the box (in addition to transforms for other effects)?